# Assuming two integers are odd

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to assume both n and k are odd in Mathematica?

```
Assuming[{n > 0, k > 0}, Exp[-I*(\[Pi]/2)*(n^k)] // FullSimplify]
```

n=1,3,5,7,...
k=1,3,5,7,...

The answer should be.

[image: s]

Comment: Your desired answer is simpler as `(-I)^n`, as can be illustrated by `Table[(-I)^n == Exp[-I*(Pi/2)*(n^k)], {n, 1, 11, 2}, {k, 1, 11, 2}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Simplify[Exp[-I*(Pi/2)*(n^k)], 
 Assumptions -> 
  n ∈ PositiveIntegers  && k ∈ PositiveIntegers && 
   Mod[n, 2] == 1 && Mod[k, 2] == 1]
```

> `I^-n^k`

```
$Assumptions = 
  n ∈ PositiveIntegers && k ∈ PositiveIntegers && 
   Mod[n, 2] == 1 && Mod[k, 2] == 1;
expr=Exp[-I*(π/2)*(n^k)] // ExpToTrig
expr // First // Simplify
expr // Last
```

`PowerMod[n,k,4]` can not be simplified. Maybe we need to simplify `Mod[n^k,4]` by hand.

Comment: I am expecting a different answer which I entered. Can we get an answer in terms of n only?

Comment: What if you replace n by 2n+1 and k similar? I do not understand your question "Can we get an answer in terms of n only?". Do you mean setting k==n?